# Share classes between blazor components

Tags: c#, class, blazor

Look, i don't know how to share classes between blazor components.

I have a component `Home.razor` and i created a class inside other file `classes/Test`, how can i use this class inside my `Home.razor`???

[Test Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clIQP.png)

[Home.razor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N6nm.png)

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usOm3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a class anywhere in your app you can reference it from any of your components.

If, for example, you create a folder called `ViewModels` you can add the following to the top of your .razor file

```
@using MyApp.ViewModels
```

Or you can edit `_Imports.razor` and put it in there and then that namespace will automatically be used by all of your razor files.